# How to enter a plus sign?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and when I try to make a simple calculator it shows me an error because I don't know how to allow the user to enter a plus sign.

My code goes like this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
sign = int(input("Enter a sign:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
result = (num1,sign,num2)
print(result)
```

It tells me:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '+'
```

I hope there is someone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

The `int` in the line `int(input("Enter a sign:"))` is trying to convert whatever the user returns into an integer. So if you say `int(input("Enter a number: "))` and the user types "7", that 7 is being returned as type str (string in python). `int` is then converting the string "7" into the integer `7`. But when you ask the user to enter a sign, say "+", and then wrap that in `int()`, you are asking python to convert "+" into an integer. What number is "+"?

Make it `sign = input("Enter a sign:")` and it will work.

Comment: I've tried removing the word (int) but when i type it as you said the math operation wont  work
it types the + as a string 

For example lets say
num1 = 1
sign = +
num2 =  1

i want the result to be 2

but the result will look like this
(1, '+', 1)

Comment: One possible solution would just be to use some `if` `elif` statements to check which symbol has been entered and then do the corresponding operation. ie `if sign == "+": answer = num1 + num2` and so on for each symbol.

Answer (score 0):

What @amengelbrecht answered was correct. The error is converting "+", which is not an integer, into an integer. Similarly, it might not be wise to convert the numbers into integers. Perhaps `float(input(Enter a number))` is a wiser option since normally calculators accept decimals too.

Additionally, if you would like to account for the user entering junk (which you should), use try and except.

```
try:
    num1=float(input("Enter a number"))
    ...
except(ValueError):
    print("Please enter a number instead")
```

ValueError is exactly what you got just now when you tried to convert "+" to an integer, so it ensures that the data you get is proper and it will not cause the program to stop, so perhaps you might be using a while loop or smt, the program will continue despite being fed rubbish.

(I would have left a comment if i could, but i cant)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you the conditions. Mee too used that when I created my first calculator:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
sign = str(input("Enter a sign:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))

if sign == "+":
    print(num1+num2)
elif sign == "-":
    print(num1-num2)
elif sign == "/":
    print(num1/num2)
elif sign == "*":
    print(num1*num2)
```

I changed the int in sign variable to str, because the + sign is not an interger and I think it should be used as a string as every special character.
Then I used the if condition which acts like a filter.

If the sign variable is equal to +, the result is calculated as shown in the print. If it is not equal, the program switches to the next condition, which is elif (else + if). It works the same as the first condition and so on. There is also the else statement, but it is redundant for this program.

**I hope this has helped!**